# My iPhone X is using guided access on the Lock Screen I can’t touch anything to reset it please help

Tags: iphone, ios, guided-access

I accidentally put on guided access before turning my iPhone X off.

I can’t turn off guided access and am unable to reset it as I would need to swipe the button to turn power off. It has also not allowed me to use Face ID to get things back to normal.

Do I just wait for my batteries to die or is there something else I can do to turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

To exit Guided Access session press the side button or the Home button three times (this works if you have set a Guided Access password).
For more info, see [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/guided-access-iph7fad0d10/ios) Apple Support article.